# python3: re.sub works randomly

Tags: python, replace

I’ve got multiple block of text surrounded by these html tags:

```
<code type="block" lexer="python"> my text </code>
```

## Minimal working example

I need to replace them with other text (in the minimal example here, a simple string: "REPLACEMENT"). I provide two sample blocks: one is correctly replaced, the other one not: I can’t understand why, they don’t seem to be different. The test I included

```
print(old_blockCode, "\n\n", new_blockCode, "\n_______", "\n\n")
```

makes me think that the issue is in re.sub, but it beats me why.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
fileContent = """<code type="block" lexer="python">import re
for old_code, new_code in zip(codes_list, highlighted_list):
pattern = re.sub(old_code, new_code, filecontent)
pattern.append(pa)</code>
<code type="block" lexer="python">import re
inputFile = "test"
outputFile = "testout"</code>
"""
blockCodes_list = []
blockHighlighted_list = []
blockCodes = re.finditer(r'<code type="block" lexer="python">(.*?)</code>', fileContent, flags=re.DOTALL)
for match in blockCodes:
    block = match.group(1)
    blockCodes_list.append(block)
    blockHighlighted = "REPLACEMENT"
    blockHighlighted_list.append(blockHighlighted)
newfileContent = fileContent
for old_blockCode, new_blockCode in zip(blockCodes_list, blockHighlighted_list):
    newfileContent = re.sub(old_blockCode, new_blockCode, newfileContent)       
    print(old_blockCode, "\n\n", new_blockCode, "\n_______", "\n\n")   
print(newfileContent)
```

### Expected Output

```
<code type="block" lexer="python">REPLACEMENT</code>
<code type="block" lexer="python">REPLACEMENT</code>
```

### Real Output

```
<code type="block" lexer="python">import re
for old_code, new_code in zip(codes_list, highlighted_list):
pattern = re.sub(old_code, new_code, filecontent)
pattern.append(pa)</code>
<code type="block" lexer="python">REPLACEMENT</code>
```

Comment: If you ever think "it must be the compiler" or "it must be a standard library" you are almost certainly wrong. In my entire life, I've seen exactly one case, and the person who reported it had documented the bejeebees out of it because no one believes claims of "the compiler has a bug" without unequivocal proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did exactly what you asked of it. You wanted text beginning with `<code…>` tag followed by a string of anythings followed by `</code>`. And that's what it did:

```
<code type="block" lexer="python">import re
for old_code, new_code in zip(codes_list, highlighted_list):
pattern = re.sub(old_code, new_code, filecontent)
pattern.append(pa)</code>
<code type="block" lexer="python">REPLACEMENT</code>
```

Which is a special case of the maxim "You can't parse XHTML with regular expressions". Regular expressions simply cannot match nesting groups. There may come answers following this they say you can with non-greedy qualifiers, but that's mistaken.

Use an XML parser.

Comment: The blocks aren't nested, it's more a problem of greediness/laziness...so there is a trivial solution to this problem, albeit not a bulletproof one.

Comment: Thank’you very much,  you are definitely right! I’ve been playing with beautifulsoup in the meantime, and it perfectly does what I wanted, and with minimum code too (four lines!).

Comment: (I found out that the problem is the parentheses: python seems to expect them to be escaped even in the source; this is different from the behaviour of search&replace in text editors)